# Add header to line using awk

Tags: awk, fasta

I have a file with the following format:

```
AACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
ACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
CCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
CGTAGATCCGAACTTGT
```

I want to give a header to each line, using awk, where the header is equal to the line that follows, like this:

```
>AACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
AACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>ACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
ACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>CCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
CCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>CGTAGATCCGAACTTGT
CGTAGATCCGAACTTGT
```

Answer (score 2):

The -v flag allows you to set a variable. Then for each line in the file print that variable followed by the line, and then the line itself.

```
awk -v c=">" '{ print c $0; print $0; }' <file>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
$ awk '{print ">"$0;print}' file 
>AACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
AACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>ACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
ACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>CCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
CCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>CGTAGATCCGAACTTGT
CGTAGATCCGAACTTGT
```

Or:

```
$ awk '{printf ">%s\n%s\n",$0,$0}' file
>AACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
AACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>ACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
ACCCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>CCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
CCGTAGATCCGAACTTGTG
>CGTAGATCCGAACTTGT
CGTAGATCCGAACTTGT
```

Comment: Ah, thanks from me, cos for some reason I was having issues with the greater than sign.

Comment: @chooban another thing to remember is the input might potentially have spaces in *(even though the example doesn't)* so it's probably safer to use `$0` instead of `$1`.

Comment: Out by one and foxed by a symbol! I need more coffee! :)